# Get array key in map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am comparing two arrays with each other in a function and want to return an array with the highest values at each array key. In my function I have two parameters which both represent an array.

The arrays have the same length and their key values are normal index numbers

Now I just use a normal for loop:

```
var array1 = [50, 30, 44, 8];
var array2 = [12, 44, 18, 9];

function createList(arr1, arr2){
    for(var x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++){
        arr1[x] = arr1[x] > arr2[x]?arr1[x]:arr2[x];
    }
    return arr1;
}

var highList = createList(array1, array2);
```

Now I know there are other possiblities of getting this result. But what I was wondering whether you can get the current key in the map method and use that to compare it with another array.

Something in the line of:

```
var highList = array1.map(function(num){
    return num > array2[keyOfCurrentMap]?num:array2[keyofCurrentMap];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var highList = array1.map(function(num, keyOfCurrentMap){
    return num > array2[keyOfCurrentMap]?num:array2[keyofCurrentMap];
});
```

The second param passed into [the callback for `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the key.

Comment: Works as a charm, thanks for clearing this out for me.

Comment: Done! I had to wait for 15 minutes to pass after I posted my question before I was able to accept it. Thanks again.